# Using two number arrays, how can check to see if they have the same digits but in different places in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, nested-loops, function-definition

The concept I am trying to create is a guessing game where you have a randomly generated secret code that you have to guess in a few ties. If your answer is wrong the three hints it will give you are: 1) if your guess is too high or too low.  2) if there are digits that are right and in the right place.  3) if there are right digits in the wrong place.

So if the code was 803 and your guess was 837 the output would be

```
Too High, 1 digit(s) in the right place, 1 right digit(s) in the wrong place.
```

My problem comes with the function that checks to see if there are right digits in the wrong place.

```
#define DIGITS 4                     // DIGITS repersents the amout of digits in the code.3♠

int wrongPlace(int num[], int code[]){
  int n = 0 , i , j ,temp;
  
  for(i=0; i < DIGITS; i++){
    temp=num[0];
    num[0]=num[i];               // checks each digits to see if there are equal but in a differnt
    num[i]=temp;                 // place and adds one to n
    for(j=1 ; j < DIGITS ; j++)
      if(code[i]==num[j])
        n++;
  }
  
  return n;                      // n repersent the right digits that are in the wrong palce
}
```

My problem comes with a guess or code that has duplicate numbers and return a numbers that is not acuate.

So if the code was 2128 and your guess was 7249 the output would be

```
Too High, 0 digit(s) in the right place, 1 right digit(s) in the wrong place.
```

Comment: Start by writing a function which takes if a *single digit* is in the array. Then loop over that for each digit.

Comment: To test whether a digit is in the array, there's no reason to modify the array -- doing so will just confuse things and lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be modifying any of the arrays.

We can make this simpler by working on one digit at a time, and splitting this up into two problems:

1. Is the number in the correct spot in the array?
2. If not, is it anywhere in the array?

The first is a simple loop with a counter.

```
int main() {
    int code[] = {8, 0, 3};
    int guess[] = {8, 3, 7};

    int numRightPositions = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < numCodes; i++ ) {
        if( code[i] == guess[i] ) {
            numRightPositions++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d right position\n", rightPosition);
}
```

If the guess isn't in the right position, we need to check if it's in the array at all. We can write a little function for that. Loop through the code to see if the guess is there.

```
// Don't use hard coded size, or anything, in a function.
// Pass them into the function.
bool rightNumber(const int *code, int guess, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if( code[i] == guess ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And we can add that to our loop calling it if the code isn't in the right position.

```
int main() {
    int code[] = {8, 0, 3};
    int guess[] = {8, 3, 7};
    size_t numCodes = sizeof(code)/sizeof(code[0]);

    int numRightPositions = 0;
    int numRightNumbers = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < numCodes; i++ ) {
        if( code[i] == guess[i] ) {
            numRightPositions++;
        }
        else if( rightNumber(code, guess[i], numCodes) ) {
            numRightNumbers++;
        }
    }

    printf(
        "%d digit(s) in the right place, %d right digit(s) in the wrong place.\n",
        numRightPositions, numRightNumbers
    );
}
```

This can be optimized, but that's the basic implementation using functions to separate the problem into pieces.

Comment: Let me, a beginner, point out to you that your code is wrong. Consider for example guess equal to { 1, 1, 1 } and code equal to { 1, 2, 3 }.

Comment: It may go against some people's personal coding style to modify the contents of the arrays in a situation like this, and there are certainly alternatives that don't require modifying them at all, but it is certainly not incorrect to do so as long as the rest of the program is written with the knowledge that they may be clobbered.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Bugs and edge cases are left as an exercise for the reader. ;) This is homework after all.

Comment: @Schwern It is a practical approach.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In your example, it's `1 digit(s) in the right place, 2 right digit(s) in the wrong place`. That seems right. Though I can also see how it could be 1 right place, 0 wrong place if you go by pairs. It's ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This swapping of elements of the array num

```
temp=num[0];
num[0]=num[i];               // checks each digits to see if there are equal but in a differnt
num[i]=temp;
```

does not make a sense. For example if the array num contains the following elements { 1, 1, 1, 1 } then what does the swapping do?

Also this inner for loop

```
for(j=1 ; j < DIGITS ; j++)
  if(code[i]==num[j])
    n++;
```

never check the element code[0].

Also it is a bad idea to change the array num within the function.

I can suggest the following approach shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Pair
{
    size_t right_place;
    size_t wrong_place;
};

struct Pair count_places( const int num[], const int code[], size_t n )
{
    struct Pair p = { 0, 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( num[i] == code[i] ) 
        {
            ++p.right_place;
        }
        else
        {
            size_t k = 1;

            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
            {
                if ( num[i] == num[j] && num[j] != code[j] ) ++k;
            }

            for ( size_t j = 0; k != 0 && j < n; j++)
            {
                if ( num[j] != code[j] && num[i] == code[j] ) --k;
            }

            if ( k == 0 )
            {
                ++p.wrong_place;
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 4 }; 
    int code1[N] = { 2, 1, 2, 8 };
    int num1[N] = { 7, 2, 4, 9 };

    struct Pair p;

    p = count_places( num1, code1, N );

    printf( "%zu digit(s) in the right place, %zu right digit(s) in the wrong place", 
            p.right_place, p.wrong_place );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 digit(s) in the right place, 1 right digit(s) in the wrong place100us
```

Comment: Can you explain the `for ( size_t j = 0; k != 0 && j < n; j++)`

Comment: @jamxy For example if num contains { 1, 1, 2  } and code contains { 0, 0 1 } then num[0] will be found in code at position 3.  But num contains two 1. So the code also should contain two 1 that the second 1 would be right digit. The variable k contains the value  that denotes that the element num[1]  is a second 1. So within the array code we also need to find a second 1.  So when k will be equal to 0 then it means that the array code indeed contains at least two 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that checks the two arrays and computes the output string that you want, then returns 0 if the guess is incorrect, and 1 if it is correct. It does however clobber the arrays with -1s to avoid double counting, so if that's a problem you may want to pass copies of the input and code arrays to this function

```
_Bool check(int input[] ,int code[]){
  
  _Bool higher = 0;
  int numCorrect = 0;
  int numMisplaced = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i)
    if(input[i] != code[i]){ //First digit that is not the same tells us which is higher
      higher = input[i] > code[i] ? 1 : 0;
      break;
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i)
    if(input[i] == code[i]){ //Count the number of digits in the right spots
      ++numCorrect;
      input[i] = code[i] = -1; //Don't want to double count correct digits as misplaced

    }

  if(numCorrect == DIGITS){
    printf("Correct!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i) //Check for the right digits in the wrong places
    for(int j = 0; j < DIGITS; ++j){
      if(j == i) //Skip cases where indices are the same
        continue;
      if(input[i] != -1 && code[i] != -1 && input[i] == code[j]){ //Skip all the negative ones because they have been counted as right number right place
        ++numMisplaced;
        input[i] = code[i] = -1; //Don't want to double count
      }
    }

  printf("Too %s, %d digit%s in the right place, %d right digit%s in the wrong place\n",higher ? "High" : "Low", numCorrect, numCorrect == 1 ? "" : "s", numMisplaced, numMisplaced == 1 ? "" : "s");

  return 0; //Codes are not equal
}
```

Your program may also benefit from using `char[]` instead of `int[]` to save a handful of bytes, since we only need to be able to represent digits from 0-9

Comment: Let me, a beginner, point out to you that your code is wrong. Consider for example num equal to { 1, 1, 1, 1 } and code equal to { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.

Comment: As currently written the output is `Too Low, 1 digit in the right place, 0 right digits in the wrong place`. But good catch

Comment: I see that you have updated your code. But it is not very readable due to break and continue statements.

Comment: I strongly disagree

Comment: Do not worry. It is my personal opinion of a beginner. Also I think it is a bad idea to change the array code.

Comment: `break` and `continue` are definitely controversial keywords, but the usage here I believe to be very true to their purpose in the C programming language. The alternative would be much messier